# Vulnerability : Missing SPF - is this a scam?

Tags: email, email-spoofing, spf

I got an email with the following:

```
I am just looking at your SPF records then found following. SPF Records missing safe check which can allow me to send mail and phish easily any victim.

PoC:

<?php

$to = "VICTIM@example.com";

$subject = "Password Change";

$txt = "Change your password by visiting here - [VIRUS LINK HERE]l";

$headers = "From: https://www.alidropstore.com/";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);

?>
```

It then goes on to show my SPF records and shows that they are valid. I ran the domain through some SPF checkers and all good.

My question is whether this is just a chancer, whether they have a legit point or anything else? The PoC just sends the email to spam and says the email address is not valid.

Thanks

Comment: SPF by itself does not protect against phishing in the first place. Only in connection with DMARC it somehow helps. If the sender is right about your SPF setup or wrong cannot be said, since nothing is known about the setup. Just because *"some SPF checker"* declare *"all good"* says nothing, since it is unclear what they even check. A SPF policy of `v=spf1 all` is correct but still allows every IP address so send mails with your domain.

Comment: Would it be worth adding the domain name in question?

Comment: Adding domain name would at least help to evaluate the usefulness of the SPF policy. But again, SPF by its own does not actually help against sender spoofing. Apart from that: having a URL in the mail `From: ...` header does not make any sense. Whatever this is, the person seems to have no sufficient clue of how mail works.

Comment: Ok thanks - done some reading and went back to my client with some suggestions. They use the question mark instead of a hyphen so have gone back with a ELI5 explanation around this

Answer (score 1):

If that attacker is suggesting a header like `From: https://www.alidropstore.cоm/` is valid and usable to bypass [SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) (which doesn't even look at headers!), they likely don't know what they're talking about. Either way, they don't care.

This is a scare tactic and it is filled with [FUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty,_and_doubt). — I highly suggest against responding to the attacker, but if you did, I'd expect you to get a pitch for how they'll sell you some phony service that they claim will protect you somehow.

Even if your SPF is invalid or over-permissive (like `v=spf1 ip4:1.2.3.1/2` instead of an intended `v=spf1 ip4:1.2.3.1/24`), all this does is give an SPF pass to mail, which is generally a very weak indicator of legitimacy at best. SPF doesn't have teeth, that's what [DMARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC) is for. DMARC can be configured to block misaligned or broken mail, including forgeries, but messages that are not blocked by DMARC still have plenty of chances to get blocked for other reasons, including an https link as the from header.